# Maven dependency and eclipse classpath

Tags: eclipse, maven

I tried to search for existing questions but cant find any - feels like my question is quite simple but probably because it's quite specific I cant find the answers on Stackoverflow / Google.

Anyways - I have few projects with Maven that are depend on each other. In certain cases I want the dependency to be on the JAR rather than a project dependency (ie. I want the dependency to be part of the "Libraries" in Eclipse rather than "Projects" in the Build Path).

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the referenced projects in the same workspace as jar files instead of the projects, we could use the VM parameter -Declipse.useProjectReferences=false or add it in the pom file.

> ```
>     <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>     <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>2.9</version>
>     <configuration>
>       <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
>     </configuration>
>   </plugin>
> ```

See this [URL](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/prevent-module-references.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

In your project properties in Eclipse, select Maven. There is a checkbox, 'Resolve dependencies from workspace projects'. If this is checked, then the Eclipse projects are used. Otherwise the jars are used as with other maven dependencies, assuming that you've got the dependencies in your pom.xml as normal.

EDIT: If your project is not a maven project, then you'll have to create the jar outside Eclipse and add it as a jar or external jar as normal. If the project is a maven project, then the above will work.

Comment: I dont see "Maven" option under project Properties nor do I see that checkbox anywhere. I am using Eclipse Indigo and I have the maven Integration for Eclipse plugin

Comment: Are the projects actually maven projects? Do you have maven dependecies in the classpath etc?

Comment: the classpath do have maven dependencies (library dependencies to M2_REPO, etc). The project itself is not Maven Project, I tried installing the Eclipse IAM plugin to do "Convert to Maven project" but I got "The chosen operation is not currently available"

Comment: Added clarification because the dependency isn't a maven project.

Comment: What do you meant by "add it as a jar or external jar as normal" - the maven build was done outside eclipse for all projects, so the jars are all in my local REPO, when I do mvn eclipse:eclipse - it created project dependency rather than dependency to the said JAR in the REPO - that's what I am trying to get rid of since I want it to depend on the JAR itself

Answer (score 0):

Say `Client-Project` depends on `Services-Project`.  If `Services-Project` generates a JAR. In the `Client-Project` POM you would express a dependency on this JAR.  It would be something like:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group.id.of.services.project.goes.here</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact.id.of.services.project.goes.here</artifactId>
  <version>version.number.of.services.jar</version>
</dependency>
```

If services project generates a JAR called com.mycompany.services-1.3.jar, the dependency would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>services</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's what I've done, and I added <type>jar</type> as well ... everytime I do mvn eclipse:eclipse it updates my classpath to depend on the project

Comment: Then see @Matthew Farwell's suggestion.  You probably have the "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects" option selected.